# Redirect 301 cgi-bin/ to new URL

Tags: .htaccess

it's my first question here :)

I got a problem for redirecting URL:

I have old URL like **www.domain.com/cgi-bin/category.cgi?type=...**
And try to redirect them to **www.domain.com** on the htaccess

but I still have 404 error...

This is my rule :

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

I verified if there are something in the conf about cgi-bin but nothing.

I did a test with "cgi-bin2" and it works...

So what can i do ?

Comment: If you can edit server config / virtual host config -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`), restart Apache, run problematic URL and check rewrite log for exact details. This is the best advice I can give you under these circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you problem come from but why don't you try to write a perl script which will redirect to your base domain url ?

(it can work if you have, for example, just few cgi files previously used).

In your example it seems you want to redirect "category.cgi".

so, in our case, write a "category.cgi" file in your "cgi-bin" folder and write this code inside it :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# fixedredir.cgi

use strict;
use warnings;


my $URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/";

print "Status: 301 Moved\nLocation: $URL\n\n"
```

Hope it help !

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer! It's a fast solution and it's works! best regards